# Illegal assignment from String to System.Address

Tags: apex, leads

I'm trying to set the country field on the Address object on a Lead. However when I try to do:

```
mylead.address = my_country_string
```

It returns the error in the title of this question.

> Illegal assignment from String to System.Address

If I try to do:

```
mylead.adddress.country = my_country_string
```

It returns the error

> Invalid foreign key relationship: Lead.Address at line 55 column 13

How do I set the country field of the address object on a Lead if I already have a lead?

Answer (score 3):

> The compound form of the address. Read-only. See Address Compound Fields for details on compound address fields.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm

Address is a compound field, above is documentation for compound fields

Below is Lead Object documentation showing Country for the field on lead

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm

> **Country**: Country for the address of the lead

You should be using `lead.Country`